# Powerbuilder - PB17 Upgrade issue

Tags: powerbuilder

We are facing some problem in PowerBuilder 17 version upgrade. Actually we searched one field value from our application screen but it was fetched the description id instead of description name.

Previously it was works fine in the earlier version but it was not working in the PB17 version. There is no logic changed in that. We just upgraded to PB17. Can anyone knows what was the problem in the drop down why it was not showing the description code instead of name.

New Version Screenshot for the drop down showing as code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKyde.png)

Old Version Screenshot for the drop down showing as code value(Name)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2vxR.png)

Note:- The code related to the description name is correct. But we want to display a name of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to re-retrieve the child datawindow for the dropdown.  Use the 'GetChild' method (to get a reference to the dddw) and then a retrieve on the dddw.  This would normally be in the constructor or open event on the window (where depends on how the window/userobject is created).